Cannot deploy vertex AI model locally using custom predictor
Following the documentation I have what I believe to be a minimal form of a custom predictor which I am trying to deploy locally.
I have a model dir which contains an empty requirements.txt and a predictor.py containing:
from typing import List

from google.cloud.aiplatform.prediction.predictor import Predictor

class MyPredictorBasic(Predictor):
        
    def load(self, artifacts_uri: str) -> None:
        pass

    def predict(self, instances: List):
        return ["foo" for i in instances]

I then have a script for running the model locally:
from google.cloud.aiplatform.prediction import LocalModel
from google.cloud import aiplatform

from model.predictor import MyPredictorBasic

display_name = "test_model"
model_path = "./model/"
project_id = "ai-play-430308"
repository = "test-repo"
image = "test-image"
region = "europe-west2"
output_image_uri = f"{region}-docker.pkg.dev/{project_id}/{repository}/{image}"
requirements_path = model_path + "requirements.txt"

aiplatform.init(project=project_id, location=region)

local_model = LocalModel.build_cpr_model(
    src_dir=model_path,
    output_image_uri=output_image_uri,
    predictor=MyPredictorBasic,
    requirements_path=requirements_path,
)

spec = local_model.get_serving_container_spec()
print(spec)

with local_model.deploy_to_local_endpoint() as local_endpoint:
    
    health_check_response = local_endpoint.run_health_check()
    
    print("health_check_response", health_check_response.content)

I get an error when calling deploy_to_local_endpoint
The entire output is:
/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py:955: RuntimeWarning: line buffering (buffering=1) isn't supported in binary mode, the default buffer size will be used
  self.stdin = io.open(p2cwrite, 'wb', bufsize)
/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py:961: RuntimeWarning: line buffering (buffering=1) isn't supported in binary mode, the default buffer size will be used
  self.stdout = io.open(c2pread, 'rb', bufsize)
image_uri: "europe-west2-docker.pkg.dev/ai-play-430308/test-repo/test-image"
predict_route: "/predict"
health_route: "/health"

health_check_response b'{}'
Exception ignored in: <function LocalEndpoint.__del__ at 0x7f129b0479a0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/andy/Documents/code/python/vertex_ai_play/.env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/aiplatform/prediction/local_endpoint.py", line 214, in __del__
  File "/home/andy/Documents/code/python/vertex_ai_play/.env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/aiplatform/prediction/local_endpoint.py", line 285, in stop
  File "/home/andy/Documents/code/python/vertex_ai_play/.env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/aiplatform/prediction/local_endpoint.py", line 346, in _stop_container_if_exists
  File "/home/andy/Documents/code/python/vertex_ai_play/.env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/docker/models/containers.py", line 452, in stop
  File "/home/andy/Documents/code/python/vertex_ai_play/.env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py", line 19, in wrapped
  File "/home/andy/Documents/code/python/vertex_ai_play/.env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/docker/api/container.py", line 1211, in stop
  File "/home/andy/Documents/code/python/vertex_ai_play/.env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py", line 44, in inner
  File "/home/andy/Documents/code/python/vertex_ai_play/.env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 242, in _post
  File "/home/andy/Documents/code/python/vertex_ai_play/.env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 637, in post
  File "/home/andy/Documents/code/python/vertex_ai_play/.env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 589, in request
  File "/home/andy/Documents/code/python/vertex_ai_play/.env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 703, in send
  File "/home/andy/Documents/code/python/vertex_ai_play/.env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 667, in send
  File "/home/andy/Documents/code/python/vertex_ai_play/.env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 789, in urlopen
  File "/home/andy/Documents/code/python/vertex_ai_play/.env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 536, in _make_request
  File "/home/andy/Documents/code/python/vertex_ai_play/.env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 461, in getresponse
ImportError: sys.meta_path is None, Python is likely shutting down

I also tried an alternative form of running the model locally:
local_endpoint = local_model.deploy_to_local_endpoint()
local_endpoint.serve()

Which result in the same error. If I step through line by line the error is triggered by local_endpoint.serve().
Any help would be much appreciated
